# How can i use computed property in v-for

Tags: vue.js

I penerate list for vue,second list in wrapper,left and right,

```
computed: {

    currentIndex () {
         for (let i = 0; i < this.listHeight.length; i++) {
             let height1 = this.listHeight[i];
             console.log(height1);
             let height2 = this.listHeight[i + 1];
             if (!height1 || (this.scrollY < height1 && this.ScrollY >=     height2)) {
             return i;
          }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this code have a question,height1 and height2 not movement,why is regular two variable inner loop.

Comment: can you also post the template code?

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
<span v-for="(index,key) in currentIndex" :key="key">

  {{index}}

</span>
```

you should edit element and content depending on what do you want to do in your template.